# How to select a row just once without checking any fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named tblMessages that has a field named **Type** .type value can be 1 for user messages and can be 2 for general messages.
in selection of user message i write this sql function:

```
SELECT * FROM tblMessage WHERE USERID=$Userid and Type=1 and ISseen=0;
```

then in another SQL code i updated that row and set ISseen=1 for specific user

```
UPDATE tblMessage SET ISseen=1 Where USERID=$userid;
```

but in selection of General messages i have a little problem.i want to select general message for all user and show it once!as i said before i can update tblmessage and set ISseen=1 then if ISseen be a value of 1 user message is not selected for another time.but for selection of general message i cant do it with `WHERE USERID=$userid`.
i dont want to insert general message for every user in table also.then
How can i select general messages ONCE for a user by my table structure?
*****////******

### Edit number 1

my tblmessage has 20000 records and just has 10 general messages.in my website when user loged in to his/her acount and go to his/her messages can see Personal Messages and General Messages.when user reach that page i Updated the tblmessage table and set ISseen==1
then when that user loged out and then came back to website and to his/her userpage that personal message didnt show again!cause the field ISseen=1.But in another way the general messages is showed again and again.cause what?cause i dont have any ISseen field for general message.
my question is what can i do then with this explanation of my table.how can i do the same thing with general messages.

Comment: its unclear what you want. Can you explain giving example please?

Comment: Why does this need the 'without checking any fields' requirement? Most easy would be to just mark it as seen based on their primary key, so I wonder why this isn't an option currently.

Comment: I _think_ you need another table... a many-many table that records which general message is seen by which user.

Comment: Create another table messageTable that will look like this .


**ID   --   Message**

  1    --  User message

  2    --  General message

now you can apply join to get message on the behalf of type .

Comment: @SalmanA thanks.i do it as my first way.but i want better way.

Comment: @Wrikken if you set isseen=1 then just YOU can see that message and no other users can see that general message after set isseen=1

Comment: Then your requirements have to change some way: you need _some_ sort of per-user record for the general message (although that could be some other table) if you want to set the message to seen. Or, if it's a web application (or you have other methods to store a little bit of data client-sided), you store the id's of the general messages users have seen in their user details / cookies / local storage / etc. (You'll probably have problems with people logging in from more then 1 location though).

Answer (score 0):

Create another table messageTable that will look like this .

**ID   --   Message**

1    --  User message

2    --  General message

now you can apply join to get message on the behalf of type .

your query will be look like this.

```
SELECT messageTable.*,tblMessage.* FROM tblMessage,messageTable WHERE tblMessage.USERID=$Userid and tblMessage.Type=1 and tblMessage.ISseen=0 and tblMessage.Type=messageTable.ID;
```

Comment: this is not the answer. this should be in comment

Comment: ok but The general message ISseen field is NULL!i dont want to put to it that anything!its unused for general messages.its looks like you say:hey i saw a message that is for everyone,i check it,then no one should see it again!---its false!isnt it?